# Using PHP with Google BigQuery

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am pretty new to Google Cloud Platform and for learning purposes I have created a simple restaurant finder using the Zomato API and hosted it on Google Cloud Platform.

Currently I have created a dataset with a CSV file I found online on the Google BigQuery platform and I ran a few simple queries like

```
SELECT restaurant_name FROM "restaurants" WHERE rating > 4.0
```

on the platform itself and the results are shown in a table format.

My question is there anyway to run simple queries using PHP to the dataset I created on BigQuery and display the results to my website hosted on the Google Cloud Platform ?

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 3):

You would start something like this

```
 composer require google/cloud-bigquery
```

and a code sample is

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
'keyFilePath' => '/path/to/keyfile.json'
]);

// Get an instance of a previously created table.
$dataset = $bigQuery->dataset('my_dataset');
$table = $dataset->table('my_table');

// Begin a job to import data from a CSV file into the table.
$loadJobConfig = $table->load(
    fopen('/data/my_data.csv', 'r')
);
$job = $table->runJob($loadJobConfig);

// Run a query and inspect the results.
$queryJobConfig = $bigQuery->query(
    'SELECT * FROM `my_project.my_dataset.my_table`'
);
$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery($queryJobConfig);

foreach ($queryResults as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

More example on: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php

Comment: How do i use composer on Google App Engine? Is there a way to install it to Google App Engine?

Comment: Composer works automatically on App Engine. Your vendor folder will be one level above `require '../vendor/autoload.php';`